# From rows to columns using Peewee ORM

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, peewee

I have a Peewee object that looks like:

```
class Status(peewee.Model):
    host = peewee.ForeignKeyField(
        Host,
        backref='checks',
        on_delete='CASCADE')
    check_date = peewee.DateTimeField()
    status = peewee.TextField()
```

This records the results of running some service checks on a number of hosts. Each row contains a single result for a single host, consisting of the date of the check and the status. The resulting table looks something like:

```
+----+---------+----------------------------+---------+
| id | host_id | check_date                 | status  |
+----+---------+----------------------------+---------+
|  1 | 123     | 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | UP      |
|  2 | 321     | 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | REFUSED |
|  3 | 555     | 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | UP      |
...
| 50 | 123     | 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | TIMEOUT |
| 51 | 321     | 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | UNKNOWN |
| 52 | 555     | 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | UP      |
+----+---------+----------------------------+---------+
```

I want to produce a summary view, like this:

```
+----------------------------+-----+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| check_date                 | UP  | REFUSED | TIMEOUT | UNKNOWN | TOTAL |
+----------------------------+-----+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | 221 | 34      | 10      | 2       | 267   |
| 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | 230 | 30      | 15      | 4       | 279   |
+----------------------------+-----+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

I might do it in SQL like this:

```
select
  check_date, 
  count(*) filter (where status = 'UP') as UP,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'REFUSED') as REFUSED,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'TIMEOUT') as TIMEOUT,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'UNKNOWN') as UNKNOWN,
  count(*) as TOTAL
from status
group by check_date
```

How would I structure a similar query using [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)? I know that there is access to sql functions via the `peewee.fn` namespace, but I'm not sure if it's possible to structure those `filter` subqueries using that syntax.

I've solved it for now by starting with:

```
status_summary = (
    Status.select(Status.check_date,
                  Status.status,
                  peewee.fn.Count(Status.id).alias('count'))
    .group_by(Status.check_date, Status.status)
    .order_by(Status.check_date, Status.status)
)
```

Which gets me:

```
+----------------------------+---------+-------+
| check_date                 | status  | count |
+----------------------------+---------+-------+
| 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | UP      | 221   |
| 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | REFUSED | 34    |
| 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | TIMEOUT | 10    |
| 2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036 | UNKNOWN | 34    |
| 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | UP      | 230   |
| 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | REFUSED | 30    |
| 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | TIMEOUT | 15    |
| 2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062 | UNKNOWN | 4     |
+----------------------------+---------+-------+
```

Which I then process in Python using `itertools.groupby`:

```
status_summary = itertools.groupby(status_summary, lambda x: x.check_date)
status_summary = [
    {'date': date, 'summary': {x.status: x.count for x in results}}
    for date, results in status_summary
]
```

Which gets me:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2020-02-04 17:52:28.716036",
    "summary": {
      "OPEN": 538,
      "REFUSED": 13,
      "TIMEOUT": 41,
      "UNKNOWN": 4,
      "UNREACHABLE": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-02-04 17:55:22.655965",
    "summary": {
      "OPEN": 533,
      "REFUSED": 15,
      "TIMEOUT": 42,
      "UNKNOWN": 5,
      "UNREACHABLE": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-02-04 18:51:31.937254",
    "summary": {
      "OPEN": 541,
      "REFUSED": 11,
      "TIMEOUT": 41,
      "UNKNOWN": 4,
      "UNREACHABLE": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-02-04 21:21:48.319062",
    "summary": {
      "OPEN": 544,
      "REFUSED": 9,
      "TIMEOUT": 39,
      "UNKNOWN": 4,
      "UNREACHABLE": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-02-05 00:11:23.377746",
    "summary": {
      "OPEN": 547,
      "REFUSED": 8,
      "TIMEOUT": 37,
      "UNKNOWN": 5,
      "UNREACHABLE": 1
    }
  }
]
```

This is effectively what I want, but I feel like the process of getting here was unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 3):

I would use CASE but COUNT/FILTER should work on Postgres.

```
select
  check_date, 
  count(*) filter (where status = 'UP') as UP,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'REFUSED') as REFUSED,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'TIMEOUT') as TIMEOUT,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'UNKNOWN') as UNKNOWN,
  count(*) as TOTAL
from status
group by check_date
```

Peewee should support something like this:

```
(Status
 .select(
     fn.date_trunc('day', Status.check_date).alias('date'),
     fn.COUNT(Status.id).filter(Status.status == 'UP').alias('up'),
     fn.COUNT(Status.id).filter(Status.status == 'REFUSED').alias('refused'))
 .group_by(fn.date_trunc('day', Status.check_date)))
```

But you can actually just lean on GROUP BY to give you something much simpler:

```
(Status
 .select(
     fn.date_trunc('day', Status.check_date).alias('date'),
     Status.status,
     fn.COUNT(Status.id).alias('count'))
 .group_by(fn.date_trunc('day', Status.check_date), Status.status))
```

This gives you a row for each date + for each status, but is a bit more flexible (since you don't hardcode all your statuses).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But if I understand correctly, this is identical to the query in my question (`status_summary = (
    Status.select(Status.check_date,
                  Status.status,
                  peewee.fn.Count(Status.id).alias('count'))
    .group_by(Status.check_date, Status.status)
    .order_by(Status.check_date, Status.status)
)
`), except that it uses `date_trunc` to modify the date display.

Comment: The first query gives you the summaries in a single row, the second query gives you one-row-per date per summary. Just use the first query.